# set custom JSON object names in a for loop

Tags: javascript

How do I set custom JSON object name in a for loop.

```
var myArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i<= 8; i++){

    var x = "name" + i;

    myArray.push({x:[0,0,0]});

}
```

I want this

```
myArray = [
            {name0:[0,0,0]},
            {name1:[0,0,0]},
            {name2:[0,0,0]},
            {name3:[0,0,0]},
            {name4:[0,0,0]},
            {name5:[0,0,0]},
            {name6:[0,0,0]},
            {name7:[0,0,0]},
            {name8:[0,0,0]},
            ];
```

but it returns this

```
myArray = [
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            {x:[0,0,0]},
            ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bracket notation:

```
for (var i = 0; i<= 8; i++){
  var obj = {};
  obj['name'+ i] = [0,0,0];
  myArray.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use variables as keys in an object, you should use bracket notation :

```
var myArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i<= 8; i++){

    var x   = "name" + i,
        obj = {};

    obj[x] = [0,0,0];

    myArray.push(obj);

}
```